# Case Ownership Access visiblity

Tags: case, queue, admin, insufficient-privileges

Is their any settings?

When case is created it's assign to queue which is "ExtQueue" when case Ownership change ExtQueue to "IntQueue" its changed which is working fine.
Query is when we go to created case its showing "Insufficient Privileges" error message how we can see or access Intqueue like if IntQueue is not working so we can reassign to ExtQueue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that `Cases` which are created are **Private** in your scenario. Changing their permissions can solve your problem. Here are some methods to give `Case` access:

1. If it is **Public Read/Write** or **Public Read/Write/Transfer**

   Go to Sharing settings, and Change Setting Activity object to **Controlled by Parent** and your users have **Read/Write** access to the parent object(`Cases`), they may be able to edit activities they don't actually own.
2. If it is **Private** or **Public read Only**

   Needs to Create a Sharing rule for role to role or group to group that as you need with **READ/WRITE**,  Give the **MODIFY ALL** Permission for CASE object to respective profile. (If you need to give particular user, since the profile is assigned with other users as well, Create permission set and assigned to user)

Go to Sharing settings, and Change Setting Activity object to "Controlled by Parent" and your users have read/write access to the parent object(Cases), they may be able to edit activities they don't actually own..

**However** Giving **Modify All is not recommended** because it allows users to delete case/activities which they don't own.